# Need to add a column to a pd.df using a function from a package - TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-3.6

Trying to add a column to a pandas dataframe which is calculated using implied_volatility() function from pyvollib (`from py_vollib.black.implied_volatility import implied_volatility`). All input parameter come from the following df:

```
In [101]: odf.head()
Out[101]: 
       Expiry      K Type     close         F  texp         r
7  2018-01-26  120.5    p  0.015625  122.9375    10  0.012604
10 2018-01-26  121.0    p  0.015625  122.9375    10  0.012604
11 2018-01-26  122.0    p  0.062500  122.9375    10  0.012604
17 2018-01-26  121.5    p  0.015625  122.9375    10  0.012604
19 2018-01-26  122.5    p  0.140625  122.9375    10  0.012604
```

the function i am using:

```
odf['iv'] = [implied_volatility(discounted_option_price = odf.close,F=odf.F,K=odf.K,
                 r=odf.r,t=odf.texp/365,flag=odf.Type)
                 for rows in odf]
```

the problem seems to be the column odf.Type which is a series of strings.

Traceback I am getting in ipython:

```
In [102]: odf['iv'] = [implied_volatility(discounted_option_price = odf.close,F=
     ...: odf.F,K=odf.K,
     ...:                  r=odf.r,t=odf.texp/365,flag=odf.Type)
     ...:                  for rows in odf]
     ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-133149ca6fb0> in <module>()
      1 odf['iv'] = [implied_volatility(discounted_option_price = odf.close,F=odf.F,K=odf.K,
      2                  r=odf.r,t=odf.texp/365,flag=odf.Type)
----> 3                  for rows in odf]

<ipython-input-102-133149ca6fb0> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 odf['iv'] = [implied_volatility(discounted_option_price = odf.close,F=odf.F,K=odf.K,
      2                  r=odf.r,t=odf.texp/365,flag=odf.Type)
----> 3                  for rows in odf]

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py_vollib/black/implied_volatility.py in implied_volatility_of_discounted_option_price(discounted_option_price, F, K, r, t, flag)
     97         K,
     98         t,
---> 99         binary_flag[flag]
    100     )
    101     if sigma_calc == FLOAT_MAX:

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __hash__(self)
   1043     def __hash__(self):
   1044         raise TypeError('{0!r} objects are mutable, thus they cannot be'
-> 1045                         ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1046 
   1047     def __iter__(self):

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

any pointers how to get this running would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
odf['iv'] = odf.apply(lambda x: implied_volatility(discounted_option_price = x.close,
                                                   F=x.F,
                                                   K=x.K,
                                                   r=x.r,
                                                   t=x.texp/365,
                                                   flag=x.Type), axis=1)
```

Or also:

```
odf['iv'] = odf.apply(lambda x: implied_volatility(x.close,
                                                   x.F,
                                                   x.K,
                                                   x.r,
                                                   x.texp/365,
                                                   x.Type), axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
odf['iv'] = [implied_volatility(discounted_option_price = odf.loc[i,'close'],F=odf.loc[i,'F'],K=odf.loc[i,'k'],
                 r=odf.loc[i,'r'],t=odf.loc[i,'texp']/365,flag=odf.loc[i,'Type'])
                 for i in odf.index]
```

There might be some better way of doing it using apply but i don't know how it works for named arguments.